# CursorLineNR highlight not working

Tags: vimrc, highlight

I have a vim configuration file (~/.vimrc) with the following settings:

```
colo delek
syntax on

highlight clear CursorLine
highlight clear CursorLineNR
highlight clear LineNR

highlight LineNR cterm=none ctermfg=Yellow ctermbg=none
highlight CursorLineNR cterm=bold ctermfg=Black ctermbg=none
```

This used to work fine, highlighting the current line number in Black, while the others remained Yellow. After I read about `syntax enable`, I tried it, replacing the `syntax on` command. Since then, the CursorLineNR highlighting has refused to work. I have tried changing changing the `syntax` command to `off`, `enable` and `on` in all orders but to no avail. I even tried changing the CursorLineNR from the command-line mode but that too doesn't work. It has to be noted though that the LineNR functionality works perfectly fine.

I work on a Macbook Air, with the following vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
```

Comment: So you're saying that the highlight has the values you expect (according to return value of `:hi CursorLineNR`) but those values are, as far as you can tell, being ignored?

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved it with `set cursorline`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug.
I my case, in vim 8.2, I can't highlight CursorLineNR when 'relativenumber' is set.

From the doc:

> CursorLineNr  Like LineNr when 'cursorline' is set and 'cursorlineopt' is
>           set to "number" or "both", **or 'relativenumber' is set**, for
>           the cursor line.

So, here's my workaround:

- set 'cursorline'
- highlight cursorline with the same values as for 'normal'
- then highlight 'cursorlinenr'

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In Vim you need to set number highlighting on first:

```
if !has('nvim')
    set cursorline
    set cursorlineopt=number
endif

highlight LineNR cterm=none ctermfg=Yellow ctermbg=none
highlight CursorLineNR cterm=bold ctermfg=Black ctermbg=none
```

Neovim behaves slightly differently in that `cursorlineopt` doesn't exist and `set cursorline` will act as `set cursorline | set cursorlineopt=both` in Vim.