# How can I still see underscores with cursorline?

Tags: highlight, cursorline

### Background and problem

I've just discovered [how to make the cursor a vertical line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42118416/1944384) in insert mode. This works well with [cursorline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6489348/1944384); even with the thinner cursor, I can still easily find my position.

```
autocmd InsertEnter * set cul
autocmd InsertLeave * set nocul
```

However, the default underline makes it hard to see literal underscore characters `_`.

### Attempts

1. I know I can change the highlighting of `CursorLine`, which would make underscores visible again, but this breaks syntax highlighting.
2. [Another option](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/45t1on/how_to_make_underscores_more_visible_with/czzyzdq/) is to highlight the underscore character itself in Insert mode. However, this seems like overkill, because I don't want every single underscore highlighted. Also, it doesn't work for areas that are syntax highlighted.

```
syn match underscore "_"
autocmd InsertEnter * hi underscore ctermbg=grey cterm=none ctermfg=black
autocmd InsertLeave * hi clear underscore
```

3. I also know that I can change the cursorline to bold, italics, etc., but this is also visual overkill.
4. An ideal solution would be to make the cursorline underline be a light colour, with the literal underscore a darker black, but it seems that cursorline always inherits `ctermfg`.

Is there a simple way to still see underscores, while using cursorline?

I'm using regular terminal vim (in Terminator generally), not gvim.

Comment: Have the cursor blink? Perhaps conditional on the line containing underscores?

Comment: Do you mean instead of using cursorline? I'm not a big fan of blinking things generally from a UX perspective. You have to wait half a cycle before anything is clear.

Comment: No offense but you've ruled out an awful lot of options. ;)

Comment: See if you can get any ideas from `:h 'gcr'`.

Comment: Haha yes… the fact that vim can be customised so readily has resulted in high expectations, and me being spoilt! I'll have a look now.

Comment: How about highlight cursorline with a background color instead? `hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=black` (or another color, depending on your background...) Why do you say that (1) breaks syntax highlighting?

Comment: @filbranden The background colour is used for some syntax highlighting, e.g. spellcheck.

Comment: @BLayer Oh, that's only for gvim. I'm using terminal vim. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Regarding interaction of cursorline and spellcheck, you might want to look into: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15013033/9447571

Comment: Yeah, you didn't specify but I would have pointed you to it anyways. It works in a limited capacity for console and in a general sense it talks about various ways to display a cursor...it's what spurred me to suggest blinking to you.

Comment: @filbranden Thanks for the link. That would certainly work for spellcheck, but there's also search, diff, matching parens, and several others, so a general solution would be preferred… although maybe that's not possible.

Comment: @BLayer Ah right. FWIW it doesn't seem to work for my VTE3 terminal.

Comment: You should be able to use `t_SI`, `t_SR`, etc to achieve some of it (if, for example, you decided to try blinking).

Comment: @BLayer Thanks for the clarification. I don't really understand the syntax from the help, but if only blinking or height of the block can change, it's probably not a solution anyway.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that, for you, there is no solution. :D

Comment: @BLayer You might be right :(

Comment: Ah, well...it's only a couple hours old. Lot's of knowledgeable people around here.

Comment: Thanks for your help @BLayer

Answer (score 1):

I actually went with coloring the background of the line number. This way you're not interfering with syntax colors or underscores.

So basically I have this (for light background terminal)

```
highlight CursorLineNr ctermfg=white guifg=white ctermbg=darkgrey guibg=darkgrey cterm=bold gui=bold
```

Comment: Not a bad option (+1), although [this bug](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17073/cursorlinenr-highlight-not-working) breaks it, but obviously it would be ideal if the whole line could be highlighted instead.

Comment: To complete this answer, you also need to turn off normal cursorline highlighting, e.g. with `highlight CursorLine ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=NONE gui=NONE cterm=NONE`, and enable highlighting at all with `set cursorline`.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting the underline at the line above the CursorLine is perfect (though I can't find such a solution)

My currenct setting:

```
let g:rice_white_wf='#fdf6e3'

set cursorline
hi CursorLine gui=bold guifg=none guibg=none

    " hi CursorLine guibg=rice_white_wf gui=undercurl
    " syn match underscore "_"
    " hi underscore gui=reverse
hi Visual  guifg=rice_white_wf guibg=#dde6d3 gui=bold
```

effect (use bold instead of underline for cursorline)

[image]

Comment: This answer would benefit from an [edit] explaining how it solves the problem. As written, the code block doesn't give a lot of insight into the problem or solution.